# USB Mouse stops working after NVIDIA proprietary driver installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, usb, mouse, proprietary

After installation of NVIDIA drivers (331.38) through Driver Manager on Ubuntu 14.04, after a while usb mouse stops working without any success of reconnecting it (only reboot helps). When falling back to nouveau everything works properly. I couldn't find anything related to this problem in here or anywhere else.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04d9:fa50 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1b1c:0a03 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2687:fb01  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: What kind of usb mouse?

Comment: Either Anker 8200dpi or A4Tech X7 XL-750BH. This is essentialy disabling my access to any linux distro at the moment, thus forcing me to switch back to Windows, which I dislike heavily.

Answer (score 0):

Install the input driver package :

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```

Comment: It's already installed and problem still occurs, which is very strange.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: didn't work for me